# Why does $\mathbb{w}$ not compile correctly?

Tags: math-mode

I'm using the following code to generate a math-typed `$W$` in a LaTeX document. The preamble is given for reference,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{W}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

`\mathbb{W}` renders correctly when placed in its own equation environment,

[image]

However as part of a larger equation or in an inline math environment  `\mathbb{W}` renders as the greater than or equal sign,

[image]

The code used for inline math is for example,

```
set $\mathbb{w}$ has
```

An equation that does not render is for example,

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{w}^* 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Can you please show how you input the formula where `\mathbb{W}` shows wrongly?

Comment: I updated the question. I just noticed that the same `$\mathbb{W}$` does render correctly in a later paragraph.

Comment: You can only use uppercase letters as arguments to `\mathbb`

Comment: OMW!! Cant believe I missed that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use capital letters to correctly render `mathbb`:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{W}^* 
\end{equation}
```

does render what you want.